# LaunchNavigator availableApps is returning empty even if google maps is installed

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, angular8, ionic5

I have this code :

```
constructor(
    private launchNavigator: LaunchNavigator
) {

}

getApps() {
   this.launchNavigator.availableApps().then((result: any) => {
       console.log(result);
   });
}
```

Available apps is empty when I try in ios. On Android is working fine. Can you help me please with some advices ?

Answer (score 0):

as an iPhone user, you can NOT make google maps your default navigator. Your only option is Apple Maps. so I think you deleted Apple Maps and the function availableApps() is not finding it. install it again and try again with Apple Maps instead.